# How can I access Mac menu bar help via keyboard?

Tags: key-bindings, osx, menu-bar, mac

I'd like to be able to search Emacs's Mac menu bar entries using the keyboard, as you normally do in [most other Mac applications using](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/get-help-on-your-mac-hlpvw003/mac) `s-?` ([this answer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/get-help-on-your-mac-hlpvw003/mac) suggest that it should be possible?).

I've unbound  `s-?` from calling `info`, but that has not helped in allowing me to access the help search via the keyboard.

Comment: What does this have to do with Emacs? Is this about the Emacs menu-bar (e.g. a Mac menu in the Emacs menu-bar)? If so, use [La Carte](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LaCarte) or `t-m-m-mode`. If this isn't about Emacs, please delete the question. Thx.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify; I assumed Emacs was implied given where I posted it. La Carte does not seem to use the native mac menu bar; helpful, but not quite what I'm looking for I think.

Comment: I still don't understand. What does the "native mac menu bar" have to do with Emacs? Is that used for the Emacs menu-bar? If so, then how/why doesn't La Carte or `t-m-mode` work? You don't make clear the relation between the "native mac menu bar" and Emacs. Does Emacs make use of that native menu bar? If not, then how is this a question about Emacs?

Comment: At least on my system, emacs on Mac (whether the standard version or the Mitsuharu version) *does* use the native Mac menu bar, and it does show the search field. However it does not bind the menu search to a key. I don't believe there is a way to access the menu search from emacs.

Comment: BTW, I meant `tmm-menubar`, not `t-m-mode`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to access the menu search feature from Emacs directly, but there is a workaround if you are using the [Mitsuharu version of Mac Emacs](https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac/src/master/): use `M-x` `menu-bar-open`, then type the standard key `Cmd-?` to open the menu search. You might try binding `s-?` to `menu-bar-open` so that you can get to the search by pressing it twice.

Comment: ```menu-bar-open``` is available also with <f10> key.